# bash loop through file replace string

Tags: bash, shell, loops, file-io

I have a file called file.txt that contains the following:

```
123
223
Lane,id,s_id_sample_id
1,3_range.single_try,N76
2,44_range.single_try,N77
3,92_out_range.double_try,N79
```

I like to loop through this file and do the following:

> begin from line after 'Lane' then split using comma and take the second column (id)
>      then take the id column and split on underscore, then
>       search and replace all dots and underscores with 'X' EXCEPT THE LAST TWO UNDERSCORES. So do not search and replace the last underscore (e.g. double_try).

So will like to end up with:

```
123
223
Lane,id,s_id_sample_id
1,3Xrange_single_try,N76
2,44Xrange_single_try,N77
3,92XoutXrange_double_try,N79
```

This is what I have done:

```
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2; do
 sed -e 's/_/X/g;s/\./X/g;s/'
 echo "$f1,$f2"
 done < "$file" > output
mv output $file
```

The problem is how can I specify to ignore the last two underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by first replacing the last two dots or underscores with `'@'`, then replacing the remaining dots and underscores with `'X'`, and finally, replacing all the `'@'` characters with underscores:

```
IFS=','
while read -r f1 f2 f3; do 
  f2=$(sed 's/[._]\([^._]\+\)[._]\([^._]\+\)$/@\1@\2/;s/[._]/X/g;s/@/_/g' <<< "$f2")
  echo -n "$f1"
  [[ -n $f2 ]] && echo -n ",$f2"
  [[ -n $f3 ]] && echo -n ",$f3"
  echo
done < "$file" > output
mv output "$file"
```

If `'@'` is likely to occur in your input data, you may want to use a different character. Anything that you can be reasonably sure won't occur in your input will do.